# Dividir um layout em 2 com diferentes percentagens

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Queria saber com eu faço para dividir um *layout* em 2 com 70/30 de percentagem.
Eu arranjei uma forma de dividir, porem essa forma não fica optimizada para todos os dispositivos.
[image: Isto é como está neste momento]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize um LinearLayout e recorra ao atributo [android:layout_weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight) para definir, [proporcionalmente](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight), o espaço que cada View ocupa:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <SeuLayoutDaEsquerda
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="70"/>

        <SeuLayoutDaDireita
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="30"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

A soma dos valores indicados no atributo `android:layout_weight` corresponde a 100% do espaço total. No caso presente 100% corresponde a 100(podia ser outro valor).

Assim, ao indicar `android:layout_weight="70"` no primeiro, estamos a dizer que ele deve ocupar 70 partes(70/100) do espaço total.

Da mesma forma, ao indicar `android:layout_weight="30"` no segundo, dizemos que o espaço a ocupar por ele deve ser 30 partes(30/100) do espaço total.

Nota: A utilização do atributo `android:layout_weight` obriga que, de acordo com a orientação do LinearLayout, o `android:layout_width` ou `android:layout_height` seja definido com "0dp".

Comment: Só funciona com LinearLayout?

Comment: `layout_weight` sim. Existe o PercentRelativeLayout. Nunca utilizei e o mesmo foi declarado obsoleto na API level 26.1.0.

Comment: A partir da API 21 o Gridlayout passa também a ter o conceito de weight através do uso de `android:layout_columnWeight`.

Comment: Muito obrigado duvida esclarecida, agora tenho muito trabalho pela frente para mover tudo para android: layout_columnWeight

Comment: Também funciona com ConstraintLayout, e eu acho bem melhor com ele.

Comment: @itscorey Sim, usando [Chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains), mais propriamente a *Weighted chain*.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o atributo `layout_weight`(peso) em cada *view*, atribuindo o valor `0.7` representando 70% e `0.3` representando 30%. Veja um exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7">

        <!--seu conteúdo aqui-->

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3">

      <!--seu conteúdo aqui-->

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Só funciona com LinearLayout?

Comment: @Humbertovieira para este caso, acredito que sim. Porém o android:layout_weight é usado em EditText, Buttons etc.